# VS15 Developer Command Prompt "Access to the path is denied"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, command-prompt, access-denied

In Visual Studio 15 Developer Command Prompt, I am trying to run a .bat file, but keep running into this error:
"Access to the path 'D:.....\something.cs' is denied.
To fix the problem I have:
1) Closed all other files and applications.
2) In the drives security settings set all users (including the admin) to Full control.
3) Ran the prompt both as user and as admin.

I dont know what else to do.
All I get from google is "try administrator setting".

All help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please share output from `attrib "D:.....\something.cs"`. The file could be marked as read-only.

Comment: The file is marked as read-only. But as far as I understand that should not prevent it from execution.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this problem occurs due to multiple unspecified errors in out solution.
What I have do to solve it, which works some of the time, is to make sure to make 'Get latest' from the Source Control Explorer instead of directly on the solution.

Other times, when this is not enough:

1. In the solution navigate to the project that will not build.
2. Open the folder in the file explorer.
3. Navigate to the bin/Debug folder -> Delete all files.
4. Back to Source Control Explorer -> Get latest.
5. From your solution open the folder that causes problems in the file explorer (just as before).
6. The folder should now be populated again. Open properties on each file in the folder that causes problems. Tick 'Read only' off. -> Apply -> Ok.
7. Build the project again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this pain and what I found was that if you have several projects and you have referenced one project in the other then make sure that you have manually deleted all instances of the file being called out in the error in all the projects.  I also did a restart.